# How to plot 3D electric field strengths in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, numerical-computing

So basically I`m trying to plot the electric field strength at a given point [x,y,z] in MATLAB. I want to plot the field strength at a given point in terms of color; a high field strength at point [x_1, y_1, z_1] would, for example, be shown as a dark red color, and a low field strength at point [x_2, y_2, z_2] would be shown as a light red color (approaching white color as field strength approaches zero). By field strength I mean E = sqrt((E_x)^2+(E_y)^2+(E_z)^2).

So for those counting, I have 4 "dimensions" I want to plot: 3 spatial dimensions ( x,y,z coordinates in space showing the field strength at a given point) and 1 "strength dimension" showing the field strength at that given spatial point. I want to represent this strength dimension as a color scale. The field strength should **not** show the direction of the field at a given point, just the magnitude, and it should show this magnitude as the "darkness" of a given color.

Can this be done? Most 3D plotting functions in MATLAB that I've looked at either plots a vector Z as the "height" of a function that takes as its input an X vector and Y vector, or it plots all (u,v,w) components of the field at a given point (x,y,z) as arrows, with the field strength being represented as the length of the arrow.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at [`scatter3`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html) ?

Comment: Of course I hadn't lol. That's exactly what I need, thanks!